# Objective C, what [NSString initWithFormat] exactly does?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, mkannotation, stringwithformat

I just would like to know the difference between the line 1 and 2 bellow:

```
_subtitle = @"Test"; //Line 1
_subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test"]; //Line 2
```

If I asked that question, it is because I got a problem by using MKAnnotation. In the method bellow, I try to update the subtitle delegate property of MKAnnotation (which is nonatomic, copy and readonly). But it's look like that I got a zombie when using the line 2 and nothing when using the line 1. So my question is why?

```
- (void) initCoordinateWithAddress:(NSString*)address;
{
self.address = address;

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString: address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks,NSError *error)
{
    CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    _coordinate = place.location.coordinate;
    _title = self.address;
    _subtitle = @"Test"; //Line 1: don't crash
     _subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test"]; //Line 2: crash
    //_subtitle = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"[%.2f,%.2f]", self.coordinate.latitude, self.coordinate.longitude] copy];
    _isInit = YES;

    [self.customDelegate didCalculateCoordinate: place.location.coordinate forAnnotation: self];
}];
```

}

I actually already fixed my problem by using the method copy, but I still not understand what is the difference between the line 1 and 2, if anyone can help me to understand what the difference is, I will appreciate.

Edit:

1- I am not using ARC

2- _subtitle comes form @synthesize subtitle = _subtitle; And subtitle is a part of the MKAnnotation protocol, with the property nonatomic, readonly and copy

Regards,
Cyril

Comment: I think this answer fits to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4154419/883799

Comment: You can check this nice answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275131/pros-and-cons-of-using-nsstring-stringwithstringsome-string-versus-some

Comment: Last you are executing this code in a block, this can cause issues.

Comment: Is this code using ARC or manual reference counting?  Also, what is the declaration of `_subtitle`?

Comment: Thank you for you answers.

So _subtitle come form @synthesize subtitle = _subtitle;
And subtitle is a part of the MKAnnotation protocol, with the property nonatomic, readonly and copy.

And, I am not using ARC.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using ARC, the answer is straightforward and is what Anoop Vaida wrote.  However, I think some further explanation is needed.

This line

```
_subtitle = @"Test";
```

Creates a reference to a string literal.  If you take a peak at its retain count in the current implementation of foundation, you'll find it is a very large number ([NSIntegerMax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW113) I think).  If the code for `-release` and `-retain` comes across this value for the retain count, they do not decrement or increment it.  Thus string literals have infinite life times.

This line:

```
_subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test"];
```

creates a string you do not own.  Unless you take steps to claim ownership, it could disappear at any time, most likely when the autorelease pool is drained.  Your options are create a string you do own

```
_subtitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Test"];
```

or to retain it.

```
_subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test"];
[_subtitle retain]; // Can be combined with the previous line if you like.
```

or to copy it

```
_subtitle = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test"] copy];
```

Note that, in all cases, you need to release the previous value of _subtitle before you overwrite it, or you will get a leak e.g.

```
[_subtitle release];
_subtitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Test"];
```

This is why it is better to have a property.  Just because the MKAnnotation subtitle property is read only, does not mean you can't override it with your own read/write property.  e.g.

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

// other stuff

@property (readwrite, copy, nonatomic) NSString* subtitle; 

@end
```

If you then synthesize it, you'll get all the correct memory management code and you can just do

```
[self setSubtitle: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"test"]];
```

or, if you must use dot notation

```
self.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"test"];
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just would like to know the difference between the line 1 and 2
> bellow:
>
> _subtitle = @"Test"; //Line 1
>
> _subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test"]; //Line 2

If you ask just the above these both are same.

While checking  your code,  the difference is quite visible.

You are creating a new `autorelease`d `subtitle` which is getting released once the block is over.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem with ARC

Comment: Ok, but i'm not using ARC.
So the line 1 doesn't create an autorelease? So why we never release a  object declare in the same way than the line 1?
Cheers,

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer if you are not using ARC.  I was going to write a long comment to explain this in more detail, but I'll write an answer instead.

Comment: @JeremyP: sure buddy. We will come to know more in detail.

Answer (score 1):

*I don't think your solution is to understand how the string initializes work, but more on how blocks deal with variables.*

When I think about it I think you may want to try an access _subtitle by it's property and not it's ivar.

```
self.subtitle
```

This should increment the retain count and keep everything functioning fine.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem with ARC

Comment: Why just because ARC does all the memory management doesn't mean that a variable doesn't need to increment it's retain count. Which doesn't happen with accessing an ivar?

Comment: But ARC should increment the retain count for you - assuming the variable is `__strong`

Comment: Exactly, that does not happen when you access an ivar directly.

Comment: yes it does with ARC.  I admit it might possibly be broken if you do it in a block

Comment: Hmm, good to know. :) As for it being in the block I think the value needed to be assigned in order to create the reference, as stated here. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I can't do this because the subtitle property is readonly, so they don't have any setter to update this attribute.

And, I'm not using ARC!

Comment: The entire point of MKAnnotation is to be able to set it's properties for each object. If I were you, I would change it and use the property settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the documentation for [`initWithFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithFormat%3a) it links you to [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943) with many examples.

This basically allows (s)printf-style format strings, like so:

```
NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"A string: %@, a float: %1.2f",
                                                     @"string", 31415.9265];

// string1 is "A string: string, a float: 31415.93"
```

The key is to specify arguments by adding a `,` after the string argument.

Comment: There are no format specifiers in `@"Test"` therefore, no arguments needed.

Answer (score 0):

The '[NSString stringWithFormat:]' allows you to add a variable into the string, for example:

```
int myVar = 3;
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This number is %i", myVar];
```

The resulting string would be (if you were to NSLog it, for example): "This number is 3"

However you cannot do it like this:

```
NSString *myString = @"This number is %i", myVar;
```

Which would present you with an error.